# @font-face stops working randomly, until a lot of refreshes

Tags: css, font-face

I generated the webfont kits from font squirrel. the work perfectly. I switched around the order of the fonts, moving svg fonts to the top of the order, so that they have aliasing in chrome.

They normally load perfectly and everything looks great. but sometimes, I'll load the page and the fonts have no padding, and get all stuck together. Here is an image of my menu on such an occasion:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/48sbb.png

normally it does not look like that.

I checked the chrome developer console to see what was going on and I see this:

```
GET http://localhost/mysite/css/fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.svg 404 (Not Found) coveralls-overalls-c-21.html:1
GET http://localhost/mysite/css/fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.svg 404 (Not Found) coveralls-overalls-c-21.html:1
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:56
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:56
GET http://localhost/mysite/css/fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.woff 404 (Not Found) coveralls-overalls-c-21.html:1
GET http://localhost/mysite/css/fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.woff 404 (Not Found) coveralls-overalls-c-21.html:1
GET http://localhost/mysite/css/fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.ttf 404 (Not Found) coveralls-overalls-c-21.html:1
GET http://localhost/mysite/css/fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.ttf 404 (Not Found) coveralls-overalls-c-21.html:1
```

The directories being linked to are correct.

If I refresh the page a bunch of times, eventually it all looks normal again.

here is my css for the fonts:

```
    @charset utf-8;

@font-face {
    font-family: 'allerbold';
    src: url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.svg#allerbold') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'allerregular';
    src: url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.svg#allerregular') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/typetogether_adelle-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}



@font-face {
    font-family: 'allerbold';
    src: url('fonts/aller_bd-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_bd-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/aller_bd-webfont.svg#allerbold') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/aller_bd-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_bd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');       
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'allerbold_italic';
    src: url('fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.svg#allerbold_italic') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'alleritalic';
    src: url('fonts/aller_it-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_it-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/aller_it-webfont.svg#alleritalic') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/aller_it-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_it-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'allerregular';
    src: url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.svg#allerregular') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I should say also, That as you can see in the image the font is actually being displayed. It is just the padding/margin etc that is being affected.

And when I refresh the page and the fonts display normally the errors are gone from the console.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with a facebook plugin, which could be stopping other scripts on your site working.  Try disabling facebook plugin and see if the error goes away.

Comment: I removed the facebook plugin and it does not help. It seems to have something to do with the fonts being used when in a list. So I am trying to go through all the css but I am not seeing anything

Comment: Well the 404's are coming from somewhere.  Your browser might be using a cached version of the fonts for display.  Have you tried using relative paths instead of absolute?

Comment: The 404s were a stupid mistake on my part. If you look at the css I was using the font allerbold for example but then, looking for the font adelle. This was because of a find and replace I did. In any case removing that, I got rid of the 404s. But that did not fix the issue. What was causing the issue was changing the order of calling the SVG (so that chrome displays the font nicely) apparently also causes formatting issues. Using @media screen to force the svg font to be used by chrome seems to have fixed the issue as far as I can tell